# How to install Frama-C on Manjaro 18.1.5?

Tags: makefile, frama-c, opam, manjaro

I'm trying to install frama-c on my distro of manjaro 18.1.5, but no matter what I try, I always have an error.

First I tried to install via the AUR, and it seems to work, but when i try to open a file from the gui, it fails and says something like "invalid user input" even though I use files that works on a known good install.

**Edit**: here is the error output for this file:

```
[kernel] Parsing max.c (with preprocessing)
[kernel:annot-error] max.c:2: Warning: 
  unbound logic variable INT_MIN. Ignoring logic specification of function max
[kernel] User Error: warning annot-error treated as fatal error.
[kernel] User Error: stopping on file "max.c" that has errors. Add '-kernel-msg-key pp'
  for preprocessing command.
```

Then I tried to install it using opam, so I first try to install dependencies with depext but it does not install anything then when I tried to install frama-c, it fails with the following error :

```
<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] The compilation of frama-c failed at
        "/home/benoit/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build make -j7".

#=== ERROR while compiling frama-c.20.0 =======================================#
# context     2.0.5 | linux/x86_64 | ocaml-system.4.09.0 | https://opam.ocaml.org#2d21a0b6
# path        ~/.opam/default/.opam-switch/build/frama-c.20.0
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build make -j7
# exit-code   2
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/frama-c-4880-6d07ae.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/frama-c-4880-6d07ae.out
### output ###
# [...]
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/legacy/eval_terms.cmx
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/domains/cvalue/cvalue_transfer.cmx
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/legacy/eval_annots.cmx
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/engine/transfer_logic.cmx
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/domains/cvalue/cvalue_domain.cmx
# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtksourceview-2.0
# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# Ocamlopt     src/plugins/value/domains/cvalue/cvalue_specification.cmx
# File "_none_", line 1:
# Error: Error while building custom runtime system
# make: *** [Makefile:1294: bin/viewer.byte] Error 2
# make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

My final attempt was to build it from source, but the make fails with the following error :

```
Ocamlc       src/plugins/server/jbuffer.cmo
File "src/plugins/server/jbuffer.ml", line 23, characters 12-26:
23 | type json = Yojson.Basic.t
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound type constructor Yojson.Basic.t
make: *** [share/Makefile.generic:78: src/plugins/server/jbuffer.cmo] Error 2
```

My only remaining solution is to use a VM with debian but it's really ideal for me...
Does anyone have an idea of what i could do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your question, and I believe some of them are worthy of investigation as possible bugs or issues. I'd recommend trying one of the official Frama-C support channels:

- Creating an issue in the [Frama-C Gitlab public repository](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c);
- Or creating an issue in the [Frama-C Github snapshot repository](https://github.com/Frama-C/Frama-C-snapshot) (currently being deprecated in favor of the Gitlab repository, which is updated daily);
- Or trying some interactive opam-related support in the IRC `#frama-c` channel on freenode.net (interactive support is often more efficient for installation issues related to opam, especially since it's hard to know in advance which information might be useful).

#### Dealing with "Invalid user input" errors in the GUI

As a general rule, when trying to open a file in the GUI fails, I'd recommend running the command-line version of Frama-C with the filename. Its output is much more detailed and can indicate if there are parsing issues with the file (which could be due to missing dependencies, non-C99 syntax, or configuration problems).

Otherwise, the Console tab in the GUI should contain detailed error messages, which you could then add to this SO question, in case they are relevant to understand your issue.

#### Issues with graphical libraries in non-major Linux distributions

The second issue I can see in your question, is the error related to `-lgtksourceview-2.0`. This means that one of the library dependencies for the graphical interface is missing. Maybe there's a way to fix it, but at the very least it should be possible to identify the error before compilation, and report the incompatibility earlier. The fact that `depext` did not work is unusual; maybe it's not currently well-supported for Manjaro, but it's worth investigating. Unfortunately, opam can sometimes be complex to handle for first-time users, so I understand it's a bit frustrating and may take more time than you'd want. But if you intend to use Frama-C or other OCaml packages for some reasonable amount of time, it is worth understanding some of the common errors in opam, since it is very useful for handling dependencies.

#### Handling issues with OCaml dependencies when compiling manually

Finally, the issue with Yojson is probably due to the version of the package that is installed. In particular, versions before 1.6.0 do not have the type `Yojson.Basic.t`. Frama-C used to support 1.4.1, but the latest version requires at least 1.6.0. Again, it's not obvious to spot in advance all possible issues with different package versions, but reporting them allows us to include checks to prevent it in the future, or at least to give a more precise error message.

Normally opam handles that part, hence why it's recommended even for manual compilation of Frama-C, since it helps manage its dependencies.

Overall, it seems that some underlying issue with the dependencies in opam depext is preventing the whole chain from working properly. Your report does contain much useful information but not all the details, so I believe the interactive route should allow to quickly converge towards a working installation.

Comment: Regarding "The fact that `depext` did not work is unusual": when there are alternatives dependencies (for Frama-C, lablgtk2 or lablgtk3), `depext` is known to not always make the same choice as the `install` target (see  https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/15439#issuecomment-561899872). It might be worth it doing `opam depext conf-gtksourceview` before retrying `opam install frama-c`.